# How to revert implicit access permission to a folder in macOS?

Tags: macos, security

In macOS some folders are protected in the sense that you have to allow an app to access them: Downloads, Documents, Desktop and a few others. Even if you haven't allowed some app to access, say, Documents, it still may open a file or folder inside Documents [if done through standard file dialogs](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125182). For example, I denied permission to access Documents to Code, but then opened some folder F inside Documents as a project and Code was able to see it perfectly. Now, is there a way to revert this implicit permission to access F? I might have given access to it by mistake. It's easy to check that the permission is still there. If I open a terminal in Code I can list the contents of F with ls, while previously I couldn't.

According to the [app sandbox documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox/accessing_files_from_the_macos_app_sandbox) the app is persisting access with a [securely-scoped URL bookmark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox/accessing_files_from_the_macos_app_sandbox#4144043). So I guess my question is how can I remove this bookmark, preferently without writing code.